# Solspace Calendar error: "Column 'repeat_weeks' cannot be null"

Tags: error, solspace-calendar, entry

EE 2.11.8, Solspace Calendar 1.8.14 (vastly out of date, I know, I know... old client site. * *le sigh* * )

I'm trying to post a new Calendar Event entry. When I set it to not repeat, or to repeat yearly, it works fine. However, if I choose to have it repeat daily, weekly, or monthly, I get the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1048

Column 'repeat_days' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `exp_calendar_events_rules` (`event_id`, `calendar_id`, `entry_id`, `rule_type`, `start_date`, `all_day`, `start_time`, `end_date`, `end_time`, `repeat_years`, `repeat_months`, `repeat_days`, `repeat_weeks`, `days_of_week`, `relative_dow`, `days_of_month`, `months_of_year`, `stop_after`, `stop_by`, `last_date`) VALUES ('230', '72', '230', '+', '20170621', '', '1300', '20170621', '1400', 0, 0, NULL, 0, '', '', '', '', 0, '20170628', 20170628)

Filename: third_party/calendar/data.calendar.php

Line Number: 997
```

I've checked the console to see if there are any JS errors, thinking perhaps the Calendar fieldtype might be having an issue with modern browser JS, but there's no apparent problems.

This site is hopefully going to be revamped this summer, but until then, I just need this to work properly. Can anyone point me to a fix, whether it's a code change, database field requirement change, or something else? Much grass!

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Solspace Calendar but I think what is happening here is that EE is just passing through an error generated from MySQL.

I'm *pretty sure* that if you `ALTER` your `exp_calendar_events_rules` table so that the column `repeat_days` allows `NULL` values the error will go away.

But is it possible this will have consequences on the operation of the Calendar module so you would definitely want to try it on a dev instance of the site.

Comment: The problem is that I'm _trying_ to create a repeating event, so I would think that the `repeat_days` column _should_ have a value of some sort. It's kinda like the form isn't successfully conveying the repeat parameters to the PHP that's doing the processing.

Comment: Ah right. I think you have to hope @ solspace or @JimWyse happens by or consider submitting a support request https://solspace.com/expressionengine/create-ticket/calendar In my experience Solspace is very responsive.

Comment: Ahh, thanks, I'll submit a ticket and report the solution here. For some reason I thought Solspace did support here; I think I was confusing things with P&T's approach. :)